# Precalculus Roots of Unity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots-of-unity

Let $A$ be the set of all complex numbers $z$ such that $z^{24}=1$ and let $B$ be the set of all complex numbers $w$ with $w^{54}=1.$ That is
\begin{align*}
A&=\{z\;|\;z^{24}=1\}\\
B&=\{z\;|\;z^{54}=1\}\\
\end{align*}
Finally let $C$ be the set of all numbers that can be formed by multiplying an element of $A$ by an element of $B:$

$C=\{zw\;|\;z\in A,w\in B\}.$

How many distinct elements are there in $C?$

Hi guys,
I have been having some trouble with this problem.  I have tried using the 24th roots of unity, but has gotten me nowhere so far.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: some roots are both roots for $z^{24}$ and $z^{54}$ eg. $1$ and $-1$. Are there others like that?

Answer (score 1):

The $24$th roots of unity are $e^{2\pi i x/24}$ and the $54$th roots are $e^{2\pi iy/54}$, where $x,y$ are integers.  So the elements of $C$ are
$$e^{2\pi i((x/24)+(y/54))}=e^{2\pi i(9x+4y)/216}\ .$$
So, we need to know how many different residues modulo $216$ are taken by the expression $9x+4y$.  The answer is, all of them: since $9$ and $4$ are relatively prime, the equation
$$9x+4y=m$$
has a solution for any integer $m$, and so it certainly has a solution for $m=0,1,\ldots,215$.

Thus, the number of elements in $C$ is $216$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about roots of unity as points evenly spread out on the unit circle, or if you connected the dots, as a polygon pointing right.

If you were considering cube roots of unity, you'd have one point at $1+0i$ and two points spread equally far apart—an equilateral triangle.  If you were considering fifth roots of unity, you'd get something like [this](http://www.mathematics-online.org/inhalt/aussage/aussage381/img5.png).

More interestingly, you can multiply roots of unity (this can lead to what's called a cyclic group).  If you pick a root—a point on the unit circle; we'll call it $R$—and multiply by another root $S$, you'll end up at yet another root.  In fact, you're starting at $R$ and rotating around the origin by the angle between $1$ and $S$.  More or less, all we're doing is $$1^{x/54} \times 1^{y/54} = 1^{(x+y)/54}.$$

Knowing that multiplication by a root of unity is a rotation, we can frame the problem in some different ways.  One of them might be, "If I have 54 copies of a 24-gon, each one rotated by 1/54th of a circle from the last, how many vertices will overlap?  How many distinct point will there be?"  Your final answer would be the starting number of vertices, 54 x 24 = 1296, minus the number of duplicates.  (Taking this *particular* approach may not be your best bet; there are a lot!)

Also, check out this nearly identical question on StackExchange: [Number of elements in sets of roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853797/number-of-elements-in-sets-of-roots-of-unity?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

We are in Z_lcm[24,54]=Z_216and so the number is 216